# How to override model in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Basically I have two module.

1. estimator
2. finance

I have one table that named "Repair_Estimate", 
so it will be interprated as a model.

But, I want to separate them into two namespace based two module above.

So in model's folder like this :

```
models
   - estimator
        -RepairEstimate.php
   - finance
        -RepairEstimate.php
```

So, in estimator's model,  RepairEstimate is defined like this :

```
class RepairEstimate extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
    public function rules(){
      return [
         //some rules here
        [['inspection_id', 'IDENTITY'], 'required', 'on' => 'pre'],
      ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels(){

        //some attribte here
        return [
         'id' => 'ID',
        ];
    }
}
```

My question is, in finance's models, it defined like this :

```
class RepairEstimate extends \app\models\estimator\RepairEstimate
{
public function __construct(array $config = [])
{
    parent::__construct($config);
}

public function rules()
{
        // How to add some rule here ?
    return parent::rules(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    // How to add some attribute here ?
    return parent::attributeLabels(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP `array_merge` function:

```
public function rules()
{

    return array_merge(parent::rules(), [ 
          //your additional rules here
    ]);
}


public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array_merge(parent::attributeLabels(), [
          //your additional attribute labels here
    }
}
```

Or if you want to change existing ones:

```
$attributes = parent::attributeLabels();
// do something with $attributes array
return $attributes;
```